# Blank page removal and explanation of command

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I am using this thesis template, and it has a blank page before every new section like Abstract, Acknowledgement etc. I searched around and found out that 
`\cleardoublepage`
 is used for this purpose of starting the section at odd numbered page and leave a blank page if necessary. The .sty file contains the following :

```
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else%
    \hbox{}%
    \thispagestyle{empty}  % Empty header styles
    \newpage%
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

% Acknowledgement Section
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{
\cleardoublepage
\setsinglecolumn
\chapter*{\centering \Large Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{empty}
}
```

First I tried removing just the `\cleardoublepage` from Acknowledgement section but that did not remove the blank page, but then I removed the first `\hbox()` command from `\renewcommand` and that removed all the blank pages before sections.

I am kind of new with LateX so if someone can explain what `\renewcommand` in this code is doing?

Comment: It redefines  `cleardoublepage` so that the empty page (if any) has no page numbering, i.e. is really a blank page. What would you like to have?

Comment: I would just like no empty page. Can you explain the command line by line, what each sub-command is doing, I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\clearpage` starts a new page and causes all floats (tables, figures, &c.) so far appeared to be placed. 
Then `\if@twoside` (tests if you're in a two-sided document; if yes, it proceeds)`\ifodd\c@page`(tests if current page is odd; if yes, does nothing) `\else%
    \hbox{}%` (if no, puts an empty box on the even page)
    `\thispagestyle{empty}  % Empty header styles`(ensures  ther's no page number on an empty page)
    `\newpage%`(starts a new, odd page)
`if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage` (if in  two column mode, starts again a newpage, because in the first column of a page in two column mode, \newpage starts a new *column*
`\fi\fi\fi}` closes the three tests executed up to this point.

Comment: So why does removing the first hbox(), removes the blank page? I mean how is an empty box creating a blank page?

Comment: `\hbox{}` creates a ‘real‘ page. I suppose (not sure) that without this page, the `\newpage` which follows has no effect.